# Truth set with an implies statement and an intersection of family of sets equals everything?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A_0 = \{1,2\}, B = \{2,3\}, F = \{A_0, B\}$. $\cap F = \{x | \forall A (A \in F \implies x \in A)\}$

I am confused over the truth set in the intersection of $F$ because if $A \notin F$ then the statement $A \in F \implies x \in A$ will always be true.  Since if the universe of discourse is all natural numbers ($1,2,3,...)$, doesn't this mean that $\cap F$ will be every possible set of natural numbers?

Comment: It is not a lucky choice to use $A$ as quantified variable ($\forall A\ldots$) when it already denotes the fixed set $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: This depends on what $A$ ranges over in $\forall A$. My guess would be that it ranges over elements of $F$.

Comment: No it does not, as if we have $x \in F$ then we have to have $x \in A_0$ and $x \in B$ (because of $A_0 \in F$ and $B \in F$ and the definition of $\cap F$).

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Right but if we define $\cap F$ like I did so in my question, will $\cap F$ equal every set of possible natural numbers if that is our range? Also, in statements like this, is there some kind of implied range? The book I'm reading says that $\{x | \forall A \in F(x \in A)\}$ (clearly the range is defined here) is equivalent to the definition in my above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that it's fixed, the $\cap F$ refers to all $A \in F,$ so in your case it refers to the two sets $A_0$ and $B.$ It then says that $x$ should be in both these sets in order to be counted in $\cap F.$ The only such element is $2$ so the intersection is $\{2\}$ as one would expect from the simpler definition of intersection.

When we write the condition $\forall A (A \in F \implies x \in A),$ it is only saying that *if* $A \in F$ then ..., and is not making an assertion about any sets $A$ which happen not to be in $F.$

Comment: Right, but what if we ranged over some set that wasn't in $F$? What forces the range to be the elements of $F$?

Comment: @Jason -- Just tried another added explanation...

Comment: I'm still slightly confused.  What if we range over some set $C$ in our for all statement.  Then $A=C$ and we have $C \notin F$ so the statement $A \in F \implies x \in A$ is true.  We then get some undefined $x$ added to our set.

Comment: I may be thinking about it wrong, because I'm thinking of it as a programmer would. For instance, you have a function which returns true or false based on $A \in F \implies x \in A$ and you feed it every possible value A.  If A isn't in F, then the function returns true

Comment: Yes, and because it returns true in the case that $A \notin F$, the only sets $A$, that we have to look at to see if $\forall A (A \in F \implies x \in A)$ is satisfied are $A_0$ and $B$. Notice that your programme has to check for all sets $A$ that the statement $A \in F \implies x \in A$ is true for $x$ to be allowed to be in $\cap F$. It will always return true for $A \notin F$ but when it comes to $A_0$ and $B$ it might return false, i.e. the $x$ we are looking at is not contained in the set, and then $x$ does not satisfy the defining statement for $\cap F$, thus is not contained in it.

Comment: @Jason -- Yes if $A$ is a set *not* in $F$ then the implication $A \in F \implies x \in A$ would be true. However keep in mind the initial quantifier "For all $A$" which appears before this implication, and it is seen that only those $x$ which are in the two originally given elements of $F$ will satisfy the quantified implication, i.e. with the "For all $A$" included in front.

Comment: Ah okay, so then it is some kind of unspoken rule that when we have the statement "For all A, if A is in D, then P(A)" we cannot use this statement for any A that is not in D?

Comment: @Jason : No, it is not an unspoken rule. Note that the truth value of the statement $\forall A (A \in F \implies x \in A)$ only depends on $x$. You cannot even talk about 'using this statement for any $A$' because you are not given the opportunity to choose any $A$. To check for a specific $x$ if the statement is correct, you have to look at (or if you like that better, 'loop over') all sets $A$ and for each of these you have to check if $A \in F \implies x \in A$ is true. If it is true for all sets $A$ (in particular for $A_0$ and $B$), then $\forall A (A \in F \implies x\in A)$ returns true.

Comment: Not quite. The for all $A$ means that $A$ is to range over all subsets of some universal set which includes at least the mentioned integers 1,2,3. And since the statement is to hold for all these $A$ it must in particular hold for $A=A_0,B$ which in fact *are* in $F$. So it's not the use of an unspoken rule, but because of the fact that $A$ must range over all the subsets, including $A_0,B$ which keeps only the 2 to satisfy the universally quantified statement.

Comment: Ok, so essentially because of the context of the statement, it knows to only keep items from the two sets, $A_0, B$ and discard items from any other sets in the universe?

Comment: It isn't the context. The statement is "For all A" so must be true for every subset A of the universal set, including $A_0,B.$ By the way, note that *if* $F$ were empty, then the intersection would end up being the entire universe, because then $A \in F$ would always be false.